# Windows 8.1 and Kali linux dual boot issue on Lenovo y410p

Tags: windows-8, display, multi-boot, kali-linux

I have a lenovo y410p with nvidia 755m after installing kali linux which by the way works perfectly I decided to check out my Windows 8. It had been split in half horizontally with the bottom half showing black and the top half showing the normal Windows which by the way overflows out of the screen.

I thought this was a problem with the installation so I installed both operating systems again and still the problem was there. I had disabled the secure boot and fast boot but still the issue was there after the installation.

I've been googling this issue but still no solution has anyone else faced this issue and if so what was your solution?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same issue. What I did was under secure boot in the bios menu, I changed the OS type from "windows UEFI mode" to "other OS" and that fixed it.